# css table column width

Tags: html, css

I have the code below. To print, the first column would like you to adjust the width to the content size. The second column would like you to adjust to the rest of the width. I do not know what the width of the first column will be, since the content will always change. The second column is always blank.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Content1</th><th>Content2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Here is the content</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using something such as an image which has a certain width after dynamically creating it you can use `width: auto;` for the cell it's in. This doesn't work with text sadly enough.

The code should explain itself:

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
tbody tr td:first-child{
width: auto;
border: 1px solid;
}
tbody tr td:last-child{
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Content1</th><th>Content2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This adjusts the width of the table for the content**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and remove:

```
colspan="2"
```

in html file

Comment: No, this set a fixed width and won't at all dynamically adjust the right column to take space left.